# File access after fsck very slow for first-time access?

Tags: ext3, storage, fsck

My drive started to show up errors, I unmounted it and ran `fsck` on it. It's a 2TB drive installed on Debian Squeeze, using `ext3`.

The `fsck` too about 17 hours. I found some, luckily mostly unimportant, files in `lost+found`.

But when I tried to access anything on that FS, first time access (reading directory listing, reading file information, reading file data) is very slow and takes up to one or two seconds. Accessing anything a second time seems to be normal.

Given that I've around 1.5TB data on it, that's a lot times for "first access after mount".

However, I don't see anything in the logs regarding this, how can I figure out what is going on? Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect bad thing about *spinup time* on your drive.

Did you check `/var/log/kern.log` ?

You may use `smartmontools` for checking drive sanity (you need root access):

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

or if in root console:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdX
smartctl -l error /dev/sdX
```

Or his graphical interface (GUI): `gsmartcontrol`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I almost forgot about `smartctl`. Unfortunately I also remember why it doesn't work: the drive is connected via usb, and smartctl only gives me this: `Unknown USB bridge [0x0411:0x00a2 (0xf320)]`. I plan to backup the data as good as possible and move it into a computer where I can run better diagnostics.